# Undefined import error Angular 2 with JsonpModule

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my app.module.ts file

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {WeatherComponent} from './weather-
 widget/component/weather.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, JsonpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, WeatherComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

When I add the *import {JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';*

I get the following error (without that import everything is fine):

> (index):25 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
>       Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14331:33)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14311:46)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17063:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17001:39)
>           at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16992:23)
>           at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6684:29)
>           at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6666:25)
>           at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:5:10)
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:7:4)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14331:33)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14311:46)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17063:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17001:39)
>           at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16992:23)
>           at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6684:29)
>           at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6666:25)
>           at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:5:10)
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:7:4)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

I have read multiple solutions on possible problems, however without any success. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. I had a mistake in the systemjs.config.js file. The @angular/http mapping had an error in the url.